# whats the best way to find multiple appearance of string within a list in python?

Tags: python

Lets say i have the following list:

> ['ab=2','bc=5','ab=1','cd=6','ab=7']

whats the best (efficient) way to find all appearance of the word 'ab' in this list

Comment: What do you mean? Do you want to collect all of the strings with 'ab' in them, or what?

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: yep, i want to collect all the strings with ab in them.

Comment: @thg435 No it doesnt for my current code, but what the solution if it does?

Comment: @DoronS: if it does, pick the `in` solution, otherwise `startswith`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
>>> mylist = ['ab=2','bc=5','ab=1','cd=6','ab=7']
>>> [i for i in mylist if 'ab' in i]
['ab=2', 'ab=1', 'ab=7']
```

Timing all the presented solutions with `timeit`, reveals that this is the fastest solution by around a factor of 2, over the next best.

Answer (score 5):

Well if the `'ab'` is always at the front this would be the most efficient unless the data is always simple like this in which case the solution by @fraxel would be the fastest.

```
>>> data = ['ab=2','bc=5','ab=1','cd=6','ab=7']
>>> [x for x in data if x.startswith("ab")]
['ab=2', 'ab=1', 'ab=7']
```

Comment: 'ab'==x[:2] is probably even quicker?

Comment: @fraxel Right, I will change it to that :D

Comment: @jamylak, interesting, you have used `x.partition('=')` instead of `x.split('=')`. It is faster or just your preference?

Comment: `x[:2] == "ab"` is usually written as `x.startswith("ab")`.

Comment: and if i want the index of them in the list?

Comment: @SvenMarnach oh right, forgot about that I will remove `partition`. To answer the question `partition` is faster.

Comment: @DoronS if you want the index: `[i for i,x in enumerate(data) if x.startswith("ab")]`

Comment: is it quicker then >[x for x in i if 'ab' in x]

Comment: @DoronS if `'ab'` is always at the front, yes.

Comment: @DoronS  Could you please clarify whether this is the case or not in the question?

Answer (score 4):

you can also use filter:

```
mylist = ['ab=2','bc=5','ab=1','cd=6','ab=7']
filter(lambda s: 'ab' in s, mylist)
```

Comment: @Thrustmaster `filter` is almost never considered the way to go in Python. List comprehensions are almost always preferred.

Comment: @jamylak: it's a matter of taste.

Comment: @jamylak: There is no specific reason to prefer a more verbose list comprehension when compact syntax will not only do just fine, but will also make it more readable. I agree with Martijin, it boils down to taste and readability.

Comment: @Thrustmaster The list comprehension is considered more readable and it is more of a pythonic thing rather than through the use of ugly `lambda`s.

Comment: I do not know which is more pythonic, but generally I tend to prefer lambdas to list comprehension. May be, lambdas are more readable only to me.

Comment: @Thrustmaster: Note that the "compact syntax" is three characters longer in this case, and it is also slower.  That usual recommendation is that `filter()` and  `map()` are fine if you don't need to define a `lambda` for them.  If you do need a `lambda`, or you would need both, `map()` and `filter()`, list comprehensions are preferred.

Comment: @SvenMarnach I agree that it's more readable. But I think it's fine to mix filter/map with lambdas if you add a comment.. I've seen many filter/map/reduce calls with long~weird expressions. Adding a comment explaining what it does seems better, atleast for me :)

Answer (score 2):

If you only to judge: Does it has `ab`. You can only by this

```
>>>data = ['ab=2','bc=5','ab=1','cd=6','ab=7' ,'abc=1']
>>>[x for x in data if 'ab' in x]
>>>['ab=2', 'ab=1', 'ab=7', 'abc=1']
```

If you need judge: Does the string before `char =`  equal `ab`. Can use `partition method`

```
>>>[x for x in data if x.startswith('ab=')]
>>>['ab=2', 'ab=1', 'ab=7']
```

This is [List Comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Comment: I originally used `partition` but realised it is the same as checking `startswith` but slower.

Comment: @jamylak yes the `partition` is slower than `startswith`. But use `startswith` the result is wrong if need decide does the substring before `=`  is equal `ab`

Comment: How does `partition` fix that? It will check the same thing.

Comment: You could simply use `startswith("ab=")` instead of partition.

Comment: @shihongzhi Actually you may be right, leave `partition` in, your other solutions have already been mentioned. The reason is, there could be a tag like `'abb=5'`